# how to fix"failed to submit action template" while publishing an google assistant app from google actions

Tags: action, google-assist-api

[image: you can see the error message at the top right corner]on google actions, when I click on submit for production, it fails and an error message appears as"failed to submit action template"
Even after completing all the procedures like simulator testing and filling in all information. The app is unable to be published because of the error mentioned.
There are no errors in the process but it fails to submit for production.

Comment: Facing same issue

Comment: facing same problem